# Why IDEA doesn't load default jars?

Tags: intellij-idea, classpath, java, autoload

I've got a similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903475/why-does-intellij-import-extra-libraries-from-jdk-1-6-for-a-simple-hello-world-pr) problem, the only difference is that it's opposite. :D I've got only jdk (using jre from jdk package). When I add this in SDKs section, I suppose IDEA should load all the necessary libs from `jdk_path/jre/lib`, but it doesn't.

What's strange is that the first time I add jdk classpath settings are just great.

Comment: What jars are not added, but should be added?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, This comes from the addressed post: "Some of the libraries are alt-rt.jar, charsets.jar, deploy.jar, dnsns.jar, javaws.jar, jce.jar, jsse.jar, localedata.jar, etc.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks more like a bug. Whenever apply key is pressed, default jars that were added to classpath earlier are just gone. Pressing OK in stead of Apply is a valid workaround. This should be reported in a bug trace system.

Comment: Please file a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA and specify what OS and IDEA version you are using.